# Launch node if not already running

Tags: ros

When doing `roslaunch <pkg> <file>.launch` I want all nodes that are launched inside that file to only start if they're not running yet. 
How do I do this? 
If it's not possible, is it at least possible to do this for each node separately?
If someone has an idea it would be great if you added that code to my example .launch snippet below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<launch>
  <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" />
</launch>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible as discussed [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/295160/change-behavior-of-killing-nodes-with-same-name/).
`roslaunch` and `rosrun` will always run the node with the desired name which results in the fact, that the `roscore` will kill living nodes with the same name.
You can use the `anon` tag to run multiple instances with always varying names as explained [here](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML#substitution_args).
The only exception to this behavior is the `roscore.xml` and its nodes as explained [here](http://wiki.ros.org/roscore).
The only current workaround, from my point of view, is writing a script which checks via `rosnode list` if the desired node is already running and depending on the outcome, run your node or not.

Answer (score 0):

Using `<arg>` tag in launch files that are connected through `<include>` tag, you can set up variables in top launch file and send to other included launch files. Then, using `<if>` and `<unless>`, you can start a node or leave it. You can find it's documentation in [ROS_Wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML).

In multiple independent launch files, things are a little different since you don't have link between launch files. You can use environment variables to replicate the results .

Comment: This does not answer the question. You are just referring to `if` and `unless` tags which cannot handle the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

you can check with the `if` tag and an `eval` statement:

```
if="$(eval not [s for s in eval('_' + '_import_' + '_(\'rosnode\')').get_node_names() if 'NODE_NAME' in s])"
```

i.e.:

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" 
   if="$(eval not [s for s in eval('_' + '_import_' + '_(\'rosnode\')').get_node_names() if 'rviz' in s])"/>
</launch>
```